# Are questions about Disk Wars on topic?

Tags: discussion

Setting aside the nature of the question, would questions on the game [Disc Wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_Wars) be on topic on this site?

Comment: For a sec there I thought you were talking about [Core War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_War) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, no problem.  Disc Wars is fully on topic.  From our [faq](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/faq) a boardgame is

1. Be playable on or around a table
2. Have objective rules of play and win conditions
3. Offer dynamic challenges, either through other players, randomization, or both
4. Be playable by hand, by human players implementing all of the rules

To my knowledge, Disc Wars has no problem clearing those requirements.